# Is the angle between $(0, \frac\pi2)$ or $(0, \pi)$

Tags: linear-algebra, trigonometry

**Lemma** $\textbf b ^{t} \in \text{span}(\textbf b^{0 }, \theta^*)$ for all $t\ge 0$. (This says that everything happens in a 2-dimensional subspace of $\mathbb R^d$.)

Define $\beta^t$ to be the angle between $\textbf b^t$ and $\theta^*$. We should regard the angle as any value between $0$ and $2\pi$. Fix an orthogonal basis $\{\textbf e_1^t,\dots,\textbf e_d^t\}$ such that

$$\langle \textbf b^t, \textbf e_1^t\rangle = \|b^t\|\hspace{1cm}\text{and}\hspace{1cm}\theta^*=\langle\theta^*,\textbf e_1^t\rangle \textbf e_1^t+\langle\theta^*,\textbf e_2^t\rangle \textbf e_2^t=\theta^*_{t,1}\textbf e_1^t+\theta^*_{t,2}\textbf e^t_2$$

and define $\beta^t\in[0,2\pi]$ to be the angle such that $$\begin{split}\cos\beta^t&=\frac{\langle \textbf b^t,\theta^*\rangle}{\|\textbf b^t\|\|\theta^*\|}\\
\sin \beta^t&=\frac{\langle \theta^*, \textbf e_2^t\rangle}{\|\theta^*\|}\end{split}$$

Then it says that $\beta^t\in(0, \frac \pi2)\Leftrightarrow \theta^*_{t,2}>0$.

I believe this is not true. If $\theta^*_{t,2}=\langle \theta^*, \textbf e^t_2\rangle>0$ then $\sin \beta^t>0$ so $0<\beta^t<\pi$, or am i wrong?

Comment: The angle between two vectors is ordinarily taken to be in $[0,\pi]$.

Comment: Yes, you are right. They actually meant $\beta^t \in (0, \pi)$, not $(0,\frac \pi 2)$. But they confused themselves. As Ted Shifrin points out, one normally takes the angle between two vectors to be in $[0,\pi]$ using the cosine formula alone, which is the range you get for vectors in an unoriented space. But when you pick a basis per their convoluted instructions, that basis can be used to force an orientation on the space, and for no apparent reason, they decided to make use of this arbitrarily chosen orientation to extend the angle range to $[0,2\pi)$.